# How does fetchLazy work in jooq?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

How does `fetchLazy` work in jooq?
Is it equivalent to doing paginated select with limit and offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're different.

#### [`fetchLazy()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--)

... returns a [`Cursor`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html) type, which is jOOQ's equivalent of the JDBC [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) type. The query will fully materialise in the database, but jOOQ (JDBC) will fetch rows one-by-one. This is useful

- when large result sets need to be fetched without waiting for the data transfer between server and client to finish - as opposed to a simple [`fetch()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch--), which loads all rows from the server in one go.
- when the client doesn't know in advance how many rows they really want to fetch from the server.

#### `LIMIT .. OFFSET`

... will reduce the number of returned rows already in the database, without them ever surfacing in the client. This can heavily improve execution speed in the server, as the server

- May choose a different execution plan - e.g. using nested loops instead of hash joins for low values of `LIMIT`
- Doesn't need to keep an open cursor for a long data transfer time, as only few rows are transferred over the wire.